# Sorting by LastModifiedTime in content search webpart is affected by attachment last modified date

Tags: content-search-web-part

I have a content search web part that is getting the 5 most recently modified items, ordered by LastModifiedTime, from a list. I am also displaying the LastModifiedTime on a custom item display template.

When I attach a document to the list item, the LastModifiedTime uses the documents data instead of the list item itself. I have tested this with excel and word files, but .txt did not cause this issue. Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a feature of SharePoint 2013 search it pulls the last modified date property from office documents.

How about mapping the ows_modified crawled property to one of the predefined RefinableDateXX managed properties and sorting by that instead.

Comment: I have tried that and ows_q_DATE_Modified and it did not return correct results. It didn't have an affect on the order at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new managed property or modify the existing RefinabkeDateXX managed property by mapping the crawler property ows_Modified.

Note: After creating the creating new managed property or modifying the existing RefinabledateXX, you will must have to run the Full Crawl. Once the Full Crawl will be done, you will able to see your desire output.